# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer

im creating a api with image uploading in mongo for a project but im getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\src\app\controllers\ProjectController.js:58:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

the error is lin line 58 in the maps

```
router.post('/', uploads.any() ,async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    try{
        const { title, description, tasks } = req.body

        const project =  await Project.create({title, description, user: req.userId });

       await Promise.all(tasks.map( async task => {
            const projectTask = new Task({...task, project: project._id})

           await projectTask.save()

           project.tasks.push(projectTask)
        }))

        await project.save()
        return res.send({ project })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(400).send({error: 'Error creating new project'})
        
       
    }
})
```

my req came like this with a console.log:

```
   title: 'titulo',
   description: 'tinha feito errado',
  'tasks.title': 'testee form',
  'tasks[][description]': 'tomara que funcione',
  'tasks[][dicionario[] [nome]]': 'Teste',
  'tasks[][assignedTo]': '605df6eab581542e58d447ac'
}
```

but I dont know how to solve this, can you help me ?

Comment: It’s possible that `tasks` is not passed as a member of `req.body`? (Can check via `console.log`)

Answer (score 3):

Try `console.log(req.body)` and check if you got the `tasks`. The error says that the `tasks` is `undefined`.

Comment: edited with the req.body, can you take a look ?